# Reasons and prevention of trivial (and less trivial) misclassification errors?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, topic-model

I was not sure about posting this question with mentioning the name of the company, which I quite respect and admire. However, I've figured that a wider exposure might help the team to fix this and similar problems faster as well as increase the quality of the *machine learning (ML)* engine of their website.

The problem exposes itself by too many occurrences of a quite trivial *misclassification error* on Amazon's book categories **classification** (which I'm a frequent visitor of). In the following example, the underlying reason of such behavior is quite clear, but in other cases the reasons might be different. I am curious about what could be other potential *reasons* for misclassification and what are the *strategies/approaches* to avoiding such problems. Without much further ado, here's how the problem appears in real life.

I was reviewing some books, related to transitioning from graduate programs (Ph.D., in particular) to work environment in academia. Among several other books, I ran across the following one:

[image]

So far, so good. However, let's scroll down a bit further to see the the books ratings in relevant categories. We should expect Amazon to figure out *categories*, **relevant** to the book's *discipline, topic and contents*. How surprised was I (and that's an understatement!) to see the following result of Amazon.com's sophisticated ML engine and algorithms:

[image]

Clearly, the only fuzzy fact that connects this book with the subject "Audiology and Speech Pathology" (!) is IMHO the author's last name (Boice), which, is **close to** the word "voice". If my guess is correct, Amazon's ML engine, for some reason, decided to take into account the book's lexicographical attribute instead of the book's most important and **most relevant attributes**, such as title, topic and contents. I've seen multiple occurrences of similar absolutely incorrect ML-based decision making on Amazon.com and some other websites. So, hopefully my question makes sense as well as interesting and important enough to spark a discussion: **What could be other potential reasons for misclassification and what are the strategies/approaches to avoiding such problems?** (Any related thoughts will also be appreciated.)

Comment: What's the category of the "Advice for new faculty members"?

Comment: @LauriK: Definitely not the one that has been selected.

Answer (score 2):

By looking at the ratings of the book, it looks like they are doing some sort of hierarchical clustering.
First of all it's a book, then a text book, then in medicine & health science.

This is a pretty difficult problem because:

1. You don't know how many and which topics you have, and the topics are constantly changing.
2. Since this is a clustering problem (or a semi-supervised problem in the better case), a closed feedback loop for these errors cannot be applied. Clustering is always more difficult than a supervised learning problem.

Apparently they're doing a pretty good job in general. This book in particular is a tough one...

Comment: Thank you for the answer (+1). I don't think that the hierarchical structure of the classification path necessarily implies the use of hierarchical clustering (HC) approach. They might be using some fancy ontology-based or other technique, different from HC. I'm not sure that they are doing a good job - as I said, I've seen multiple similar errors in the books section, which is one of Amazon's major e-commerce channels.

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh Yep, it's just a thought.